# java process useing 93% memory and not OutOfMemory

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I hava a java process A,
I use 60 thread concurrency to do stress test,
And 15 hours later, it's used 93% memory. but stil running , just get request very slow.

I got dump file. but heap or stack has nothing unusual.
when it's no request in . memory still not get down. during twice full gc. memory release to 68% , now it's 49%.

I wander why? And how to check what thing take lot of memory.
this process just do three things:

1. get dubbo request.
2. check param.
3. send to rabbitMQ

Comment: *"how to check what thing take lot of memory"* with a profiler

Comment: It isn't clear when the memory went down to 49%. while you were running the tests? If after 15 hours there were still more than 50% of free memory,  it seems unlikely that you have a memory leak. I would look somewhere else. Could rabbitMQ be overloaded after 15 hours of stress tests?

Comment: nope. after 15 hours . test is stop. in fact when 12 hours past , request is  start get slow. unil now ,no one touch this server. and memory is get down slow.

Comment: about 49%:   9:00 am, memory is 94% used. 12:00 am, memory is 68% used, and found twice full gc. 15:00 pm, memory is 49% used.

Comment: 17:00 pm it's 26% used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a headpump with jmap to view the heap contents. Depending on the GC algorithm used, the java process might fill all its available memory before trigger a GC cycle. Take a look at -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction parameter